# why "dict(Runoob=1, Google=2, Taobao=3)" will compile while "dict(1=1, 2=2, 3=3)" not in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I just write the following code:

```
test=dict(1=1, 2=2, 3=3)
```

But got the following compile error:

> test=dict(1=1, 2=2, 3=3)
>            ^ SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

code like this will compile successfully:

```
test=dict(Runoob=1, Google=2, Taobao=3)
```

why?

Comment: `1` is not a valid python identifier

Comment: `1` is not a valid keyword argument name in Python - it's an expression, not an identifier.

Comment: thanks for all of your tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use numerical keys via the dictionary constructor. This is because the constructor `dict()` uses keyword arguments to represent key-value pairs. A keyword must be a valid python identifier so numerical values are not allowed here.

But you still can do it like this:

```
a = {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}
```

Answer (score 4):

This syntax works provided that keys are valid python identifiers.

For the numerical-like keys, you can't do that. Alternative:

```
>>> test={'1':1,'2':2,'3':3}
>>> test
{'1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3}
```